# Parametrizing the curve $2 x^2 + x^4 + 2 y^2 = 1$

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, algebraic-curves, plane-curves, parametrization

> Do you know how one can find a parametrization of the following curve?
>   $$2 x^2 +  x^4 + 2 y^2 = 1$$

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: What have you tried? Do you see a rather trivial parametrisation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$x^4+ 2x^2= (x^2)^2+ 2(x^2)= (x^2)^2+ 2(x^2)+ 1- 1= (x^2+ 1)^2- 1 \tag{1}$$
We can write 
$$2x^2+ x^4+ 2y^2= (x^2+ 1)^2- 1+ 2y^2= 1 \tag{2}$$ 
so 
$$(x^2+ 1)+ 2y^2= 2 \tag{3}$$

Let $x^2+ 1= \cos\theta$, so that $x= \sqrt{\cos\theta-1}$ and $y= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sin\theta$.  Of course, that only works for $x$ positive.  For $x$ negative, use $x= -\sqrt{\cos\theta- 1}$.

(Parcly Taxel, I do NOT see a "rather trivial" parameterization!  Please enlighten us.)

Comment: Thank you so much, this is also very nice, there is no "rather trivial" parameterization guys, thats why I asked, thanks again

Comment: There is a typo in $(3)$. Your parametrization of $(3)$ is erroneous. In particular $\cos\theta-1<0$ for most $\theta$.

Answer (score 0):

We choose the parameter $t$ such that
$$2x^2+x^4=\cos^2 t,\qquad 2y^2=\sin^2 t\ .$$
Solving the second equation gives $y(t)={1\over\sqrt{2}}\sin t$. Solving the first equation gives
$$x^2=-1+\sqrt{1+\cos^2 t}={\cos^2 t\over\sqrt{1+\cos^2 t}+1}\ ,$$
so that
$$x(t)={\cos t\over\sqrt{\sqrt{1+\cos^2 t}+1}}\ .$$
The full parametric representation then is
$$\gamma:\quad t\mapsto\left\{\eqalign{x(t)&={\cos t\over\sqrt{\sqrt{1+\cos^2 t}+1}}\cr y(t)&={1\over\sqrt{2}}\sin t\cr}\right.\qquad(0\leq t\leq2\pi)\ .$$
[image]

Comment: This is correct, of course, but $y=\text{sgn}(x)\sqrt{\frac{1-2x^2-x^4}2}$ is so much simpler...

Comment: @YvesDaoust: We want a full level curve of $f(x,y):=2x^2+x^4+2y^2$. Your proposal gives two disjoint arcs on such a curve, and also the unwanted point $(0,0)$.

Comment: Thank you so much, very nice proof

Comment: @ChristianBlatter: you are quite right, $(0,0)$ is not acceptable (can be easily cured but disconnection remains).

Comment: @ChristianBlatter I got same result I guess, excepting appearance of denominator of $x(t)$.

Answer (score 0):

Tweaked from the ellipse

$$ 2 x^2+ x^4= \cos ^2 \phi;\quad 2 y^2= \sin ^2\phi ;$$
to solve a quadratic equation:

$$(x,y)=\pm(\sqrt{\sqrt{1+\cos^2\phi}-1},\frac{\sin \phi}{2}), (\phi,-\pi,\pi) $$

Axes intercepts $$\pm\sqrt{(\sqrt{2}-1)},\frac{\pm1}{\sqrt2}$$

Angle $\phi$ corresponds to the eccentric anomaly of the standard ellipse.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much dude, very nice proof